# How can deployment through a contract factory be cheaper than deploying a contract directly?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, myetherwallet

When I deploy a contract directly, the transaction uses about 3,500,000 gas.

When I deploy the same contract through a contract factory, the transaction uses about 3,000,000 gas.

In the first case, I let the remix IDE set the gas amount. In the second case, I set the gas limit to 4,000,000 gas in MyEtherWallet. I don't think the gas limit should make a difference because the transaction should return any excess.

So, how is the contract factory reducing the amount of gas used?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is the tx data. The factory stores the bytecode of the contract you create inline in its bytecode, so you don't need to supply the bytecode as tx data when you create the contract. This is opposed to creating it without the factory where you could possibly spend hundreds of thousands of gas just on the tx data.

How many bytes is the compiled contract (not the factory)? My guess is 9-13k bytes, which would account for that entire 500k (tx data is 68 gas per non-zero byte and 4 gas for zero byte).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give an answer without more details, but what *may* happen, is that the Contract Factory you use has a more optimized code than what you get compiling solidity.

In [this article](https://media.consensys.net/an-introduction-to-lll-for-ethereum-smart-contract-development-e26e38ea6c23), the author experimented with compiling solidity code or an LLL equivalent, and found that

> In a recent reimplementation I did, the LLL binary ended up 70% smaller than the Solidity equivalent.

That *could* account for the difference you have.